# information on .o files for x64 is not available: NOTE on R package checks using Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp, devtools, rtools

I am using windows and just updated to `R 4.0.3` (with `RStudio` to `1.3.959`) and ran the `R` check for one of my packages which uses `Rcpp` and `RcppArmadillo` and I got the following NOTE:

```
> checking compiled code ... NOTE
  Note: information on .o files for i386 is not available
  Note: information on .o files for x64 is not available
  File 'C:/Users/NIR_Workstation/Documents/GitHub/prospectr.Rcheck/prospectr/libs/i386/prospectr.dll':
    Found 'abort', possibly from 'abort' (C), 'runtime' (Fortran)
    Found 'exit', possibly from 'exit' (C), 'stop' (Fortran)
    Found 'printf', possibly from 'printf' (C)
  File 'C:/Users/NIR_Workstation/Documents/GitHub/prospectr.Rcheck/prospectr/libs/x64/prospectr.dll':
    Found 'abort', possibly from 'abort' (C), 'runtime' (Fortran)
    Found 'exit', possibly from 'exit' (C), 'stop' (Fortran)
    Found 'printf', possibly from 'printf' (C)
```

This NOTE is not output when I run the checks under `R 4.0.2`.
I tried to find out what was going in my package on without any success.

I have tried this as well (with `R 4.0.3`):

```
Rcpp::Rcpp.package.skeleton("aTest", example_code = TRUE)

rcmdcheck::rcmdcheck(error_on = "warning", check_dir = "check")
```

and I get the same type of NOTE as the one output for my package. Again for `R 4.0.2` this NOTE is not output.

Any idea about this NOTE? or at least any suggestions about things I could try to find out what is going on?

Thanks in advance.

---

**Updated question**:

I wanted to conduct additional tests before updating my question.

Here they are:

I made a fresh install of `R 4.0.3` in a couple of other windows machines
along with `rtools`, `RStudio` and the `devtools` package which are required to
run the example below (no pre-compiled objects hanging around). I managed to uses  `reprex()` to reproduce the NOTE I got for another template package created with `Rcpp.package.skeleton()`:

```r
mdir <- "./my_dir"
dir.create(mdir)
setwd("./my_dir")
Rcpp::Rcpp.package.skeleton("anotherTest", example_code = TRUE)
#> Creating directories ...
#> Creating DESCRIPTION ...
#> Creating NAMESPACE ...
#> Creating Read-and-delete-me ...
#> Saving functions and data ...
#> Making help files ...
#> Done.
#> Further steps are described in './anotherTest/Read-and-delete-me'.
#> 
#> Adding Rcpp settings
#>  >> added Imports: Rcpp
#>  >> added LinkingTo: Rcpp
#>  >> added useDynLib directive to NAMESPACE
#>  >> added importFrom(Rcpp, evalCpp) directive to NAMESPACE
#>  >> added example src file using Rcpp attributes
#>  >> added Rd file for rcpp_hello_world
#>  >> compiled Rcpp attributes
devtools::check("./anotherTest")
#> -- Building ----------------------------------------------------- anotherTest --
#> Setting env vars:
#> * CFLAGS    : -Wall -pedantic
#> * CXXFLAGS  : -Wall -pedantic
#> * CXX11FLAGS: -Wall -pedantic
#> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#>          checking for file 'C:\Users\raml\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpqMz20b\reprex4cd8438440a2\my_dir\anotherTest/DESCRIPTION' ...  v  checking for file 'C:\Users\raml\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpqMz20b\reprex4cd8438440a2\my_dir\anotherTest/DESCRIPTION' (612ms)
#>       -  preparing 'anotherTest':
#>      checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...     checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...   v  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information
#> -  cleaning src
#>       -  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
#>       -  checking for empty or unneeded directories
#>       -  building 'anotherTest_1.0.tar.gz'
#>      
#> -- Checking ----------------------------------------------------- anotherTest --
#> Setting env vars:
#> * _R_CHECK_CRAN_INCOMING_REMOTE_: FALSE
#> * _R_CHECK_CRAN_INCOMING_       : FALSE
#> * _R_CHECK_FORCE_SUGGESTS_      : FALSE
#> * NOT_CRAN                      : true
#> -- R CMD check -----------------------------------------------------------------
#>       -  using log directory 'C:/Users/raml/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpCM99SH/anotherTest.Rcheck' (453ms)
#> -  using R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
#> -  using platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32 (64-bit)
#>   -  using session charset: ISO8859-1
#>       -  using options '--no-manual --as-cran'
#>      checking for file 'anotherTest/DESCRIPTION' ...     checking for file 'anotherTest/DESCRIPTION' ...   v  checking for file 'anotherTest/DESCRIPTION'
#> -  checking extension type ... Package
#> -  this is package 'anotherTest' version '1.0'
#>      checking package namespace information ...     checking package namespace information ...   v  checking package namespace information
#>    checking package dependencies ...     checking package dependencies ...   v  checking package dependencies (1.4s)
#>    checking if this is a source package ...  v  checking if this is a source package
#>   v  checking if there is a namespace
#>          checking for executable files ...     checking for executable files ...   v  checking for executable files (9.7s)
#>      checking for hidden files and directories ...  v  checking for hidden files and directories
#>      checking for portable file names ...     checking for portable file names ...   v  checking for portable file names
#>   v  checking serialization versions
#>      checking whether package 'anotherTest' can be installed ...     checking whether package 'anotherTest' can be installed ...   v  checking whether package 'anotherTest' can be installed (29.5s)
#>    checking installed package size ...     checking installed package size ...   v  checking installed package size
#>       v  checking package directory
#>      checking for future file timestamps ...     checking for future file timestamps ...   v  checking for future file timestamps
#>    checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...     checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...   v  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information (689ms)
#> v  checking top-level files
#>   v  checking for left-over files
#> v  checking index information
#>    checking package subdirectories ...     checking package subdirectories ...   v  checking package subdirectories
#>    checking R files for non-ASCII characters ...     checking R files for non-ASCII characters ...   v  checking R files for non-ASCII characters
#>    checking R files for syntax errors ...     checking R files for syntax errors ...   v  checking R files for syntax errors
#> -  loading checks for arch 'i386'
#>    checking whether the package can be loaded ...     checking whether the package can be loaded ...      ** checking whether the package can be loaded ... OK
#>    checking whether the package can be loaded with stated dependencies ...     checking whether the package can be loaded with stated dependencies ...      ** checking whether the package can be loaded with stated dependencies ... OK
#>      checking whether the package can be unloaded cleanly ...     checking whether the package can be unloaded cleanly ...      ** checking whether the package can be unloaded cleanly ... OK
#>    checking whether the namespace can be loaded with stated dependencies ...     checking whether the namespace can be loaded with stated dependencies ...      ** checking whether the namespace can be loaded with stated dependencies ... OK
#>    checking whether the namespace can be unloaded cleanly ...     checking whether the namespace can be unloaded cleanly ...      ** checking whether the namespace can be unloaded cleanly ... OK
#>      checking loading without being on the library search path ...     checking loading without being on the library search path ...      ** checking loading without being on the library search path ... OK
#> -  loading checks for arch 'x64'
#>    checking whether the package can be loaded ...     checking whether the package can be loaded ...      ** checking whether the package can be loaded ... OK
#>    checking whether the package can be loaded with stated dependencies ...     checking whether the package can be loaded with stated dependencies ...      ** checking whether the package can be loaded with stated dependencies ... OK
#>    checking whether the package can be unloaded cleanly ...     checking whether the package can be unloaded cleanly ...      ** checking whether the package can be unloaded cleanly ... OK
#>    checking whether the namespace can be loaded with stated dependencies ...     checking whether the namespace can be loaded with stated dependencies ...      ** checking whether the namespace can be loaded with stated dependencies ... OK
#>    checking whether the namespace can be unloaded cleanly ...     checking whether the namespace can be unloaded cleanly ...      ** checking whether the namespace can be unloaded cleanly ... OK
#>    checking loading without being on the library search path ...     checking loading without being on the library search path ...      ** checking loading without being on the library search path ... OK
#>    checking dependencies in R code ...     checking dependencies in R code ...   v  checking dependencies in R code (475ms)
#>    checking S3 generic/method consistency ...     checking S3 generic/method consistency ...   v  checking S3 generic/method consistency (959ms)
#>    checking replacement functions ...     checking replacement functions ...   v  checking replacement functions (568ms)
#>    checking foreign function calls ...     checking foreign function calls ...   v  checking foreign function calls (575ms)
#>    checking R code for possible problems ...     checking R code for possible problems ...   v  checking R code for possible problems (4s)
#>    checking Rd files ...     checking Rd files ...   v  checking Rd files (375ms)
#>    checking Rd metadata ...     checking Rd metadata ...   v  checking Rd metadata
#>    checking Rd line widths ...     checking Rd line widths ...   v  checking Rd line widths
#>    checking Rd cross-references ...     checking Rd cross-references ...   v  checking Rd cross-references (364ms)
#>    checking for missing documentation entries ...     checking for missing documentation entries ...   v  checking for missing documentation entries (562ms)
#>    checking for code/documentation mismatches ...     checking for code/documentation mismatches ...   v  checking for code/documentation mismatches (1.8s)
#>    checking Rd \usage sections ...     checking Rd \usage sections ...   v  checking Rd \usage sections (1.3s)
#>    checking Rd contents ...     checking Rd contents ...   v  checking Rd contents
#>    checking for unstated dependencies in examples ...     checking for unstated dependencies in examples ...   v  checking for unstated dependencies in examples
#>    checking line endings in C/C++/Fortran sources/headers ...  v  checking line endings in C/C++/Fortran sources/headers
#>          checking pragmas in C/C++ headers and code ...     checking pragmas in C/C++ headers and code ...   v  checking pragmas in C/C++ headers and code
#> v  checking compilation flags used
#>    checking compiled code ...     checking compiled code ...   N  checking compiled code (27.9s)
#>    Note: information on .o files for i386 is not available
#>    Note: information on .o files for x64 is not available
#>    File 'C:/Users/raml/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpCM99SH/anotherTest.Rcheck/anotherTest/libs/i386/anotherTest.dll':
#>      Found 'abort', possibly from 'abort' (C), 'runtime' (Fortran)
#>      Found 'exit', possibly from 'exit' (C), 'stop' (Fortran)
#>      Found 'printf', possibly from 'printf' (C)
#>    File 'C:/Users/raml/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpCM99SH/anotherTest.Rcheck/anotherTest/libs/x64/anotherTest.dll':
#>      Found 'abort', possibly from 'abort' (C), 'runtime' (Fortran)
#>      Found 'exit', possibly from 'exit' (C), 'stop' (Fortran)
#>      Found 'printf', possibly from 'printf' (C)
#>      
#>    Compiled code should not call entry points which might terminate R nor
#>    write to stdout/stderr instead of to the console, nor use Fortran I/O
#>    nor system RNGs. The detected symbols are linked into the code but
#>    might come from libraries and not actually be called.
#>    
#>    See 'Writing portable packages' in the 'Writing R Extensions' manual.
#>    checking examples ...  -  checking examples (360ms)
#>      running examples for arch 'i386' ...     running examples for arch 'i386' ...      ** running examples for arch 'i386' ... OK
#>      running examples for arch      running examples for arch 'x64' ...     running examples for arch 'x64' ...      ** running examples for arch 'x64' ... OK
#>       v  checking for non-standard things in the check directory
#> v  checking for detritus in the temp directory
#>      
#>    See
#>      'C:/Users/raml/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpCM99SH/anotherTest.Rcheck/00check.log'
#>    for details.
#>    
#>      
#> 
#> -- R CMD check results ------------------------------------ anotherTest 1.0 ----
#> Duration: 1m 31.9s
#> 
#> > checking compiled code ... NOTE
#>   Note: information on .o files for i386 is not available
#>   Note: information on .o files for x64 is not available
#>   File 'C:/Users/raml/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpCM99SH/anotherTest.Rcheck/anotherTest/libs/i386/anotherTest.dll':
#>     Found 'abort', possibly from 'abort' (C), 'runtime' (Fortran)
#>     Found 'exit', possibly from 'exit' (C), 'stop' (Fortran)
#>     Found 'printf', possibly from 'printf' (C)
#>   File 'C:/Users/raml/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpCM99SH/anotherTest.Rcheck/anotherTest/libs/x64/anotherTest.dll':
#>     Found 'abort', possibly from 'abort' (C), 'runtime' (Fortran)
#>     Found 'exit', possibly from 'exit' (C), 'stop' (Fortran)
#>     Found 'printf', possibly from 'printf' (C)
#>   
#>   Compiled code should not call entry points which might terminate R nor
#>   write to stdout/stderr instead of to the console, nor use Fortran I/O
#>   nor system RNGs. The detected symbols are linked into the code but
#>   might come from libraries and not actually be called.
#>   
#>   See 'Writing portable packages' in the 'Writing R Extensions' manual.
#> 
#> 0 errors v | 0 warnings v | 1 note x
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

```r
devtools::session_info()
#> - Session info ---------------------------------------------------------------
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
#>  os       Windows 7 x64 SP 1          
#>  system   x86_64, mingw32             
#>  ui       RTerm                       
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  German_Switzerland.1252     
#>  ctype    German_Switzerland.1252     
#>  tz       Europe/Berlin               
#>  date     2020-10-18                  
#> 
#> - Packages -------------------------------------------------------------------
#>  package     * version date       lib source        
#>  assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  backports     1.1.10  2020-09-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  callr         3.5.1   2020-10-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  cli           2.1.0   2020-10-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  crayon        1.3.4   2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  desc          1.2.0   2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  devtools      2.3.2   2020-09-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  digest        0.6.26  2020-10-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  ellipsis      0.3.1   2020-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  evaluate      0.14    2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  fansi         0.4.1   2020-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  fs            1.5.0   2020-07-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  glue          1.4.2   2020-08-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  highr         0.8     2019-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  htmltools     0.5.0   2020-06-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  knitr         1.30    2020-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  magrittr      1.5     2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  memoise       1.1.0   2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  pkgbuild      1.1.0   2020-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  pkgload       1.1.0   2020-05-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  prettyunits   1.1.1   2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  processx      3.4.4   2020-09-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  ps            1.4.0   2020-10-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  R6            2.4.1   2019-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  rcmdcheck     1.3.3   2019-05-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  Rcpp          1.0.5   2020-07-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  remotes       2.2.0   2020-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  rlang         0.4.8   2020-10-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  rmarkdown     2.4     2020-09-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  rprojroot     1.3-2   2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  rstudioapi    0.11    2020-02-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  stringi       1.5.3   2020-09-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  stringr       1.4.0   2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  testthat      2.3.2   2020-03-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  usethis       1.6.3   2020-09-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  withr         2.3.0   2020-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  xfun          0.18    2020-09-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  xopen         1.0.0   2018-09-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  yaml          2.2.1   2020-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#> 
#> [1] C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.3/library
```

In addition to the above tests, I ran the same code with:

- `R 4.0.3` with `rtools35`
- `R 4.0.2` with `rtools40`
- `R 4.0.3` in linux (`x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)`)

For these three tests the checks passed cleanly.

In summary, the problem only emerges with `R 4.0.3` with `rtools40`. Is it right
to assume the issue comes from `rtools40`? If so, what are the implications for
CRAN checks/submissions?

Thanks

Comment: That suggests you have pre-compiled objects hanging around that should not be there. They seem foreign to the compiler ("no info available") and they also use routines you should not use (second set of errors, see "Writing R Extensions").  That is all in your court I fear.

Comment: And again, we are not really in a position to help as you did not provide a [minimally complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  If you could, please edit your question to make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. I am trying to run some additional tests based on your comments and see whether I can get more insights on this issue. I'll edit my initial question accordingly.

Comment: Starting from the skelton generator is very good, thanks for adding. Does `Rcpp::evalCpp("2 + 2")` return the expected answer without error, or do you have a Rtools setup issue?

Comment: `Rcpp::evalCpp("2 + 2")` delivers the expected answer. I reinstalled `R 4.0.2`, `RStudio  1.3.959` and `Rtools` and also `devtools`. I ran create a new package skeleton and ran the checks on it, but I am still getting the same NOTE. I am currently preparing a reproducible example on this, but before I post the example I want also to try in another windows machine.

Comment: I just added additional and reproducible code to my original question (see __Updated question__ "section",  I was not sure if removing what I had posted originally so I left it)

Comment: I have asked the same question on the Bioconductor devel list: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/bioc-devel/2020-October/017343.html

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I doubt that this issue to specific to OP's package because the same R CMD check note is appearing for every Bioconductor package that includes Fortran or C source code (see my previous comment). I also see if the same Note if I run R CMD check on established CRAN packages such as MASS.

Comment: @GordonSmyth  What platform?  I repeated what OP posted on my system (Ubuntu 20.04) and _of course_ it passes with flying colour. (One caveat is that I do not use `devtools`.)   So AFAICT we are *still* looking for a minimally complete verifiable example.

Comment: @GordonSmyth Reading your post now. So it is Windows. And somehow this _false positive_ of finding `abort()` etc rings a bell.  That may have happened before.  But in either case I believe this to be an _R_ issue, not an Rcpp issue.  Rcpp "simply" relies on `R CMD check` being sane.  Which it may _currently_ not be on Windows...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Only for Windows. OP is also using Windows as seen from the sessionInfo.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I agree, it can't be an Rcpp issue because essentially the same Note appears for Fortran and plain C as well Cpp or Rcpp.

Comment: So I sent the example I had created with the same `Rcpp::Rcpp.package.skeleton()` call as OP to the RHub win-builder, and on R 4.0.3 it does not create the warnings.  Logs are here for a litte while:  https://builder.r-hub.io/status/anotherTest_1.0.tar.gz-495ebf4e945247e0a206f41b863b6bc3

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Interesting. When I test my packages on RHub I also get no NOTE. On the other hand, when I create your test package with Rcpp.package.skeleton("aTest", example_code = TRUE) and run R CMD check at the Windows command prompt with Rtools40 and R 4.0.3 in the PATH I do get the NOTE. For me that's a reproducible example.

Comment: I agree that it sounds more and more like an R Core issue on Windows.

Comment: @GordonSmyth: Thank you very much for your comments and tests. I guess that this should not be a problem for package submission to CRAN. Not sure if this issue might have secondary effects?

Comment: I wonder if we need to bring this to r-devel or r-package-devel? Is this actually an R issue?

Comment: I see @DirkEddelbuettel and @ GordonSmyth using Rhub. I wonder if it passes on https://win-builder.r-project.org?

Comment: Can I suggest you take up @DirkEddelbuettel's suggestion and post this on the R-devel or R-devel R-package-devel mailing lists? This may otherwise not get resolved.

Answer (score 14):

I have had the same questions for the past few months. I noticed the same issue (false positive calls of abort etc) with R-devel for Windows some months ago.

The issue is not specific to Rcpp. I can reproduce the NOTE for packages that contain only Fortran, or only C, or only C++. I run R CMD at the Windows command prompt with Rtools40 and R 4.0.3 in the PATH. The NOTE is currently appearing in the Bioconductor 3.12 checks for hundreds of packages, seemingly for any package that contains any Fortran, C or C++ source code. As you have noted, the NOTE appears only with Windows, R 4.0.3 or higher and Rtools40. The NOTE does not appear for the same packages under Linux or Mac or for older versions of R.

I submitted a package to CRAN two days ago and CRAN did not identify the NOTE as a problem, even though I see the NOTE when I run R CMD check on the same package. So I don't think it will cause you problems with a CRAN submission.

**Update 30 March 2022**

The issue was still present in R 4.1.3 and Rtools40v2, but is now gone in R 4.2.0alpha for Windows and Rtools42.

Comment: Interesting that it does not bite at CRAN either.  Would be nice to get to the bottom of it though...

Comment: I confirm that on Windows 10 with R v4.0.3, R studio v1.3.1093, Rtools 4.0, we have the same "false positive" for abort, exit and printf, which on https://win-builder.r-project.org/ are not reported.

Comment: I can confirm this is still an issue on Windows 10 enterprise with the R 4.0.3 and the R tools 4.0 that I downloaded today. This on the two monthaversary of this bug showing up on SO.

Comment: As an alternative, while the bug get fixed, on Windows 10 you can work with the Linux subsystem, it works pretty well (tested with WSL2).

Comment: Update: Still an issue in June 2021.

Comment: The problem is still there in R 4.1.2... it is very strange because the problem dissapeared in this version but it suddenly came back :/ 
Running the code in the reproducible example (see Updated question) I get now the same results for vversion 4.1.2